# How to skip nosetests of class decorated with nose.plugins.attrib.attr in shell

Tags: python, nose

class decorator for skipping nosetests can be written like below:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr(speed='slow')
class MyTestCase:
    def test_long_integration(self):
        pass
    def test_end_to_end_something(self):
        pass
```

As per documentation, "In Python 2.6 and higher, @attr can be used on a class to set attributes on all its test methods at once"

I couldn't find a way to test the code. Running

```
nosetests -a speed=slow
```

didn't help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing unittest.TestCase parent class for your test, i.e.:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr(speed='slow')
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_long_integration(self):
        pass
    def test_end_to_end_something(self):
        pass

class MyOtherTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_super_long_integration(self):
        pass
```

Your command should select tests based on attributes, not skip them:

```
$ nosetests ss_test.py -a speed=slow -v
test_end_to_end_something (ss_test.MyTestCase) ... ok
test_long_integration (ss_test.MyTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.004s

OK
```

If you want to do fancy test selection, you can use "-A" attribute and use full python syntax:

```
$ nosetests ss_test.py -A "speed=='slow'" -v
test_end_to_end_something (ss_test.MyTestCase) ... ok
test_long_integration (ss_test.MyTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

OK
```

here is how to skip slow tests:

```
$ nosetests ss_test.py -A "speed!='slow'" -v
test_super_long_integration (ss_test.MyOtherTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
```